# Kafka Connect JDBC Connector | Closing JDBC Connection after each poll

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We are going to use use Kafka Connect JDBC Source Connector to ingest data from Oracle Databases.
We have one Kafka JDBC Connector per one Oracle Db.

Looking at the JDBC Connector implementation ,if we have N number of maxTasks per Connector (inside CachedConnectionProvider), there will be N number of JDBC Connections to the server.

These connections are kept alive and will not be closed after each poll().

Our DB Admins have strict conditions about number of live connections to the db servers.
Because of this, we are thinking of closing the JDBC Connection after each poll() since our poll times are usually 10 mins or more.

Is this supported natively by JDBC Connector or do we have to do a patch?

Comment: [Here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector) I found something that can be done using `poll.interval.ms`.                                      
                                                                                                                              Inside `"config":{"poll.interval.ms" : 3600000,}`

Comment: @champion-runner out poll internals are 10mins. This setting wont close the JDBC connection

Comment: I thought this might help, yeah you are right. Maybe you can try increasing the number of attempts to retrieve a valid connection and then it might get stop automatically.